# @ConfigurationProperties and unresolvable properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties

Suppose the following configuration bean:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="foo")
private class FooProperties {
   private String mystring;
   private int myint;
}
```

and the following `application.properties`:

```
foo.mystring = ${bar.mystring}
foo.myint    = ${bar.myint}
```

Notice the two properties are *unresolvable* since no properties starting with `bar` are defined. Here is what will happen:

- `foo.mystring` is set to the string `"${bar.mystring}"` (without resolution)
- `foo.myint` will cause a conversion error since the string `"${bar.myint}"` cannot be converted into a valid integer.

I would instead expect a kind of *Unresolvable Property* exception being thrown in this case. Just like what would happen if I had use `@Value("${foo.mystring}")`.

Is that behavior expected?
Is there a way to make SpringBoot throw such exception in this case?

Answer (score 0):

> I would instead expect a kind of Unresolvable Property exception being
>   thrown in this case.

`foo.myint` is not throwing `Unresolvable Property exception` as it is getting resolved with `${bar.myint}` whereas it fails at next step when Spring try to typecast `String` to `int` as every thing you store inside a `Properties` file is a String value unless you explicitly specified it's type, as:

```
foo.myint = (java.lang.Integer)${bar.myint}
```

> Is that behaviour expected?

Probably Yes.

> Is there a way to make SpringBoot throw such exception in this case?

Yes, for `Global` level you can use [@ControllerAdvice](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#global-exception-handling) and if you want to have it at `Controller` level then you can go with [@ExceptionHandler](https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc#using-exceptionhandler)

Comment: Agree with you with regards to the `int` property.
However, the solution you propose seems applicable to the web binding stuff. I'm concerned here with the binding of properties to classes annotated with `@ConfigurationProperties`.